# Looping jquery pegar value do button e colocar na label

Tags: javascript, jquery

Meus queridos,

Tenho uma tabela de usuários, sendo que pra cada usuário tenho um button que abre um modal:

```
{% for item in lista_usuarios %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.first_name }}</td>

        <button data-target="modal1" class = "oi" type = "button" value="{{item.id}}"  class = "btn waves-effect waves-light blue" data-index="{{item.id}}" onclick="$('#modal1').modal('open');" >
            <i class="large material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Como podem ver, o value desse button já está pegando o id de cada usuário, isso está correto.

Dentro do modal, tenho uma label e preciso que o valor desse id seja passado para ela.

```
 <input type="text" class="usuario">

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".oi").each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                alert("teste");
                $('.modal').modal();
                var id = $(".oi").val();
                alert(id);
                $(".usuario").val(id);
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

O modal está funcionando e os 2 alerts também. Porém está passando o mesmo id de usuário sempre, tá passando somente o id do primeiro usuário para a label dentro do modal.

Comment: Ao invés de fazer `var id = $(".oi").val()`, tente fazer `var id = $(this).val()`

Comment: Obrigada Anderson, era só isso! Mas você sabe me dizer pq do modo como eu fiz não estava dando certo?

Comment: Bianca, sim, pois fazendo `$(".oi")`você buscará todos os elementos da página que possuem a classe `oi` e fazendo `.val()` será retornado sempre o valor do primeiro item da lista. Com `$(this)` você seleciona apenas o elemento que deseja e, assim, `.val()` retorna o valor desejado.

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo necessidade de utilizar `$.each` nesse caso.
Siga o exemplo abaixo e implemente à sua realidade que irá funcionar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on ('click', 'table > tbody > tr > td button.oi', function (ev) {
    console.log ($(this).val());
  });
    
});

var openModal = function () {
  console.log ('Executando openModal.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>item 10</td>
      <td>
        <button data-target="modal1" class = "oi" type = "button" value="10"  class = "btn waves-effect waves-light blue" data-index="10" onclick="openModal();" >
          <i class="large material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 20</td>
      <td>
        <button data-target="modal1" class = "oi" type = "button" value="20"  class = "btn waves-effect waves-light blue" data-index="20" onclick="openModal();" >
          <i class="large material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item 30</td>
      <td>
        <button data-target="modal1" class = "oi" type = "button" value="30"  class = "btn waves-effect waves-light blue" data-index="30" onclick="openModal();" >
          <i class="large material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```